# declare -a/-A matrix (Bash)

Tags: bash, matrix, declaration

What is the difference between declare -a matrix and declare -A matrix in bash programming?

```
declare -A matrix
declare -a res

read_matrix() {
    local i=0
    local line
    local j
    while read -r line; do
        j=0
        IFS=,
        for v in $(echo "$line")
        do
            matrix[$i,$j]="$v"
            j=$((j+1))
        done
        i=$((i+1))
    done
}
```

This is a piece from a bash script that calculates the solution of systems of linear equations using the Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Run `help declare`.

Comment: BTW, what's the point of `for v in $(echo "$line")`? If you want to split your line on commas, there are better (safer, less buggy) ways to do that; for example: `IFS=, read -r -a pieces <<<"$line"` -- or just change your `while read -r line; do` to `while IFS=, read -r -a pieces; do` in the first place, then you can run `for v in "${pieces[@]}"; do` to iterate over the individual pieces.

Comment: Phooey Charles. Language. ;-)

Comment: But even if you _did_ want to use word-splitting to break on commas, `for v in $line; do` is a far more efficient way to do it than `for v in $(echo "$line"); do` (and ever-so-slightly less buggy, insofar as it reduces variances in behavior based on how `echo` is actively configured... though still much more buggy than the `read -a` approach)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I did not know about `help declare`. Thank you, this is very helpful!  I originally wrote this piece of code differently. Then I was told to use the Internal Field Separator (IFS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`declare -A matrix` creates an *associative array*: Its keys are arbitrary strings. This is a feature that was added in bash 4.0 and is not available in prior releases (such as the bash 3.2 that Apple ships), and is why you can have a comma inside your keys.

`declare -a matrix` creates an *indexed array*: Its keys are interpreted as numbers.

Comment: Worth noting also, that associative arrays _must_ be initialised with `declare -A`, whereas any variable can be used as an indexed array. Also, the subscript (index) of an indexed array is evaluated as an arithmetic expression, including eg`var == 4`, which evaluates to 1 if true, and 0 if false.